# According to the new Templar Score Ranking System, what are the different ranks?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

The new DLC which arrived today (at least on PS3) adds a new map, a new multiplayer mode and what they call **Templar Score Ranking System**.
Here is the description I found on the forums: *Adding a new layer to rankings, Templar Score compiles your multiplayer scores from the previous four weeks and splits all Abstergo recruits into ten distinct slices called Templar Grade. Your Templar Grade will be a constantly evolving measure of your worth in the Abstergo hierarchy.*

But I have several problems with this.

1. I cannot find the list of these new ten slices
2. I don't know how to identify them only based on the icons (could be fixed if the answer of the first point also gives the slices' icons)
3. There is a new screen showing the pyramid and several stats/figures on the right side. But I cannot figure how the total score is computed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are collecting the names of the ranks here:
http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/2361024388/m/5761082609/p/1

As for the symBols, nobody online seems to have compiled them yet. The top rank is the Abstergo symbol, that much is known. Under that, the best i can say is that the higher the rank, the fancier the symbol.

Lastly, as for calculating: there are three game modes. Free for all (wanted), Team (chest, manhunt), and Co-op (alliance). You have a seperate score for each mode.

This week's score is calculated by the best 3 scores this week in that game mode added together. Your total Templar Grade is the last four week's worth of these averaged out.

Example:
This week - 100, 200, 300 = 600
Last week - 100, 100, 100 = 300
No scores previous weeks.

Templar grade = (300+600) / 4 = 225

Yes, weeks you dont play count as 0 for that week.

There is also an Overall score that is basically the sum of all of your other Templar Grades.

P.S. Dont assume high ranks are good players, I've played with some pretty horrible players that are considered " Master"

Comment: I let it accepted for the computation but it seems the link is not the good one as they're not talking about levels in this thread. Could you check please?

Comment: Sorry, must have had the wrong URL in my paste-buffer. I have corrected the link, it should take you to the Ubisoft site where they are working to define all the ranks, and the size of each.